# How to determine the decimal separator in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have an ASP.net MVC website which is displaying numbers. Can I somehow determine if the user's computer is configured to use a comma or a point as a decimal separator?

I could check the different languages in Request.UserLanguages but that would not be very accurate for determining the decimal separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/Get-language-and-country-from-a-browser-in-ASPNET.aspx) how to get a `CultureInfo` from the browser language - this will get you 
a `CultureInfo` object that you can use like this:

```
var sep = browserCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
```

See [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) and [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx).

Comment: Thank you – that comes pretty close to what I need although it won’t work in every case since the decimal separator does not necessarily has to correspond with the language.

Answer (score 1):

MVC has a problem handling decimal values.

There is a great [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx) by Haack about this. It shows you how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about end user's computer, the answer is no. Unfortunately web browsers don't give you such information. All you can acquire is User's preferred language, but it is a browser setting sent-out to server via HTTP Accept-Language header. That's it.
And if you think if JavaScript will give you that, the answer is no as well. It runs in the sandbox, therefore it does not have an access to Operating System.
I am not sure if Flash could access such information (possibly), but it could be blocked by end user. The same goes for an ActiveX control, plus it is not cross-platform.

So stick to the Culture detected from web browser and format number accordingly, it is just easier that way (although it won't support end user's modification of OS settings).

Comment: Thank you. I assume your answer would be "the most correct one". But since the answer from Oded comes pretty close to what I need I am going to accept his answer.

Comment: One more quick comment: it is possible to detect the decimal separator in JavaScript with a trick: converting a decimal number to string with toLocaleString() (or similar) and then simply have a look what was used as decimal separator.

Comment: @Preli: This would be a great idea but the result is not consistent - different web browsers handle it in different way (some of them are just broken).

Comment: Yes, you are write it won't work in every case. But I guess that’s something a web developer has to get used to. Many problems only have a solution which won’t work in every situation (every browser, OS, configuration, …)